# Transition with fixed position from right to left

Tags: css, transition

I have a problem when try to make transition effect on fixed element from right to left. When I hover, all *li* elements transition too.

https://jsfiddle.net/k0fow2jb/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to a site or an example**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it fixed here

https://jsfiddle.net/k0fow2jb/3/

the important thing was to add margin-left:auto to your .side-menu li

```
.side-menu {
    z-index: 999;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 25%; 
    right: 0;
}

.side-menu li{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    transition: width 0.5s; 
  margin-left:auto;
}

.side-menu li a{
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}


.ask-questions {
    background: #19b5fe;
}
.ask-questions:hover{
  width: 150px;
}

.facebook-link {
    background: #3b5998;
}

.side-menu li:hover{
  width:150px;
}

.support-box{
    background: #dd4b39;
}
```